# Define the arrow <- as an assignment operator (like =)

Tags: r, sublimetext2, text-editor, color-scheme

I code in R with sublime text2.
When I assign a variable using = , the left member is colored.
I would like it to be the same when assigning with the arrow <-

I can't find the corresponding setting in the default setting-file, how can this be tuned?

Comment: You should provide more info, including what sublime plugins/packages you're using. I have no issue with syntax highlighting in Sublime Text for either `=` or `<-`

Comment: I actually have no packages nor plugins for R, and I am using the default extended Monokai setup. Maybe you could tell me what is your R setup?

Comment: [`R-Box`](https://github.com/randy3k/R-Box) provides the ability to use R much like you would in RStudio and ships with a copy of [`R-Extended`](https://github.com/randy3k/R-Extended) which helps with better syntax highlighting.